# Getting ValueError when trying to use np.piecewise for multivariate function

Tags: python, numpy, valueerror, piecewise

I'm trying to define a multivariate piecewise function using `np.piecewise` as follows:

```
X = np.array([
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4], 
    [5, 6]
])

pw = np.piecewise(
    X,
    [
        np.abs(X[:, 0] - X[:, 1]) < 1,
        np.abs(X[:, 0] - X[:, 1]) >= 1
    ],
    [
        lambda X: 1 + 2 * X[:, 0] + 3 * X[:, 1],
        lambda X: 1.5 + 2.5 * X[:, 0] + 3.5 * X[:, 1]
    ]
)
```

Running this snippet giives the following error:

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (3,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (3,2)
```

For context, I'm attempting to represent a map f: R^2 -> R in this example, evaluating it on each of the rows of `X` at once.

Any idea? Do I need to define the final parameter differently so that the indexing correctly broadcasts?

Comment: According to the docs, each condition array has to have the same shape as `X`.  Here they are (3,) while `X` is (3,2).  And the `funclist` is supposed to take a 1d and return a 1d.  Your's take a 2d, and return a 1d.  The docs and examples make most sense if `X` is 1d; it may be possible to work with a 2d input, but it will require a lot of care, and some experimenting, to get the dimensions right.

Comment: Did you notice that for `np.piecewise` `The output is the same shape and type as x`.  That is the map is from `f:R -> R`; it can't be `R^2 -> R`.  I ignored that stipulation until I looked at the value produced from my structured array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO `np.piecewise` is more suitable if you have two arrays from `np.meshgrid`, so that `np.piecewise` can match the condition's dimension with your array dimension.

In your case, to represent a piecewise map $f:R^2 \to R$ with input being of shape `(n,2)` and evaluated row by row (each column representing a variable), the easiest way to generate vectorized code would be simply using `np.select`:

```
def pw(X):
    return np.select([np.abs(X[:,0] - X[:,1]) < 1, np.abs(X[:,0] - X[:,1]) >= 1], 
            [1 + 2 * X[:, 0] + 3 * X[:, 1], 1.5 + 2.5 * X[:, 0] + 3.5 * X[:, 1]])
```

and `pw(X)` yields the answer you want.

Answer (score 0):

By using a structured array I could cast the 2d formulation into a 1d one:

```
In [76]: X = np.array([(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)],'f,f')
In [77]: X
Out[77]: array([(1., 2.), (3., 4.), (5., 6.)], dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
In [78]: pw = np.piecewise(
    ...:     X,
    ...:     [
    ...:         np.abs(X['f0'] - X['f1']) < 1,
    ...:         np.abs(X['f0'] - X['f1']) >= 1
    ...:     ],
    ...:     [
    ...:         lambda X: 1 + 2 * X['f0'] + 3 * X['f1'],
    ...:         lambda X: 1.5 + 2.5 * X['f0'] + 3.5 * X['f1']
    ...:     ]
    ...: )
In [79]: pw
Out[79]: 
array([(11., 11.), (23., 23.), (35., 35.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4')])
```

The numbers are repeated in `pw` because `piecewise` returns an array with the same shape and dtype as `X`, even though the `lambdas` only return scalar values.